# Can't embed Birt report into JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, birt

I set the next code for get birt report in format html and display it on frame:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  language="java" errorPage="error.jsp"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/birt.tld" prefix="birt" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Seguimiento</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../js/jquery-1.7.2/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-1.7.2/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-1.7.2/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Show report</p>
<birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="localhost:9080/WebViewerExample/demo_reporte.rptdesign"
pattern="frameset"
height="450"
width="700"
format="html"
 ></birt:viewer>
</body>
</html>
```

but I'm getting this error:

Estado HTTP 404 - /proyect/frameset

type Informe de estado

mensaje /proyect/frameset

NOTE: if I run the report directly from the Birt the viewer runs perfectly.

Comment: Why do you use CAPS RAGE?

Answer (score 0):

An iframe could work like this

```
<iframe name="birtReport" src="http://localhost:9080/WebViewerExample/run?__report=demo_reporte.rptdesign&amp;__format=html" width="700" height="450"/>
```